# Which herbs can be grown as perennials?

Tags: herbs, plant-recommendations, perennials

What are some herbs that are perennials, i.e. they return and grow the next season? I'd like to keep a garden of herbs around for cooking.

Comment: Lemon balm comes back every year in my yard

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Lots of herbs are perennial, including these basic favourites:

- Chives
- Mint
- Oregano
- Rosemary
- Sage
- Tarragon
- Thyme

Parsley will be around for a year and a bit but will start to bolt in its second spring/summer.

There's a very full list of perennial herbs [here](http://forums.gardenweb.com/forums/load/herbs/msg082153349760.html) or else [here](http://www.gardensablaze.com/Perennials/PerennialHerbs.htm).

Answer (score 6):

Fennel, in addition to the ones already listed by Tea Drinker, is also a perennial.

Answer (score 1):

What do you like to cook? Taylor your herb selection to those you want to use. Coriander is similar to parsley, but you could them go to seed, use some of the coriander seed in cooking and plant some to keep it going perpetually.  Chives I keep, cut them and they regrow, but they are hungry plants.